# Get answer from Google using python

Tags: python, google-search

I am trying to build a chatbot like Jarvis. I am using Convai API for that. However, when I ask for certain things that are new (i.e. information about an event that happened yesterday, which was not available for the API since it is pre trained on old dataset). So, I want to get information from Google if the chatbot doesn't know the answer.

However, if I search Google using Beautiful Soup and requests, the results are not accurate (e.g. When I ask, "when will the next episode of one piece will come out" the answer is "Episode 13") So please tell me what I can do to scrape the correct answer for my question.
The following code is used for scraping the internet.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def google_search(self, query):
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}"

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    search_results = soup.find_all("div", class_="BNeawe")
    answer = [result.text for result in search_results]
    return answer[0]
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Do you mean that your code incorrectly parsed data from Google's results?  Or that Google's results weren't what you expect?  I don't see how we'd be able to help with the latter...

Comment: "Episode 13" is the result i get.

Comment: The program parses the result correctly. I have checked searching google. The results are not as I expected. The expected result for the example question I have given is "One Piece episode #1099 should be released on Saturday, March 30". (Note: The above answer i said is what I got from a website)

Comment: @PiranavanR: *"I have checked searching google. The results are not as I expected. "* - We don't control Google's search results.  If you think Google should be returning different results then you'd have to take that up with Google.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Ok. then is there any alternative way to get answer to the question for my chatbot?

Comment: There is no easy answer for it. You cannot design your chatbot on one specific use-case. Hopefully there will be more meaningful response for your results very soon on google but you cannot control that. You can also try multiple search providers like 'Bing' and 'Google' and rate yourself which one has more meaning full responses.